# Creating time parameter in SSMS 2016 for SSRS report

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to create a SSRS report that allows users to search work orders by time range in addition to date. For example: requests from 5/1/20-5/27/20 that took place between 5:00 p.m. and 7:00 p.m. Below is my stored procedure from SSMS 2016, I commented out the time parameters since they're not working.  This produces the unrefined data I need and the date parameters work, it's the time parameters I'm having issues with.

```
@STARTDATE DATE,
@ENDDATE DATE
--@STARTTIME TIME,
--@ENDTIME TIME
AS

SELECT 
   [PROBLEMCODE]
  ,FORMAT([DATETIMEINIT], 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS 'DATE'
  ,FORMAT([DATETIMEINIT], 'hh:mm tt') AS 'TIME'
  ,[STATUS]
FROM [Cityworks].[azteca].[REQUEST]
WHERE REQCATEGORY IN ('WATER', 'SEWER')
AND [DATETIMEINIT] BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
--AND FORMAT([DATETIMEINIT], 'HH:mm') BETWEEN @STARTTIME AND @ENDTIME;
```

This is my first time posting, so I hope all that made sense!  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why are you formatting your results in the `SELECT`? That's what the presentation layer (SSRS here) is for. Also, if you want to compare a date and time data type to a date and time data type, just compare it: `AND DATETIMEINIT >= @StartTime AND DATETIMEINIT < @EndTime`

Comment: I'm a new SQL user, so I'm still learning what needs to be in the query vs SSRS.  When I run the comparison you provided, I get this error 'The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator.' I don't get an error when I use BETWEEN, but it doesn't do anything either.  Would it be better to take the parameters out of the procedure and set them up on SSRS?

Comment: That makes no sense, You have a column called `DATETIMEINIT`, so it *must* be a `datetime`/`datetime2`/`datetimeoffset` and then both your parameters are declared as a `date`. You won't get that error with those data types

Comment: You're correct, it is set up as datetime, but when I uncomment the time parameters I get that error. I was mistaken on the BETWEEN, it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, assuming that `DATETIMEINIT` is a `datetime`/`datetime2`/`datetimeoffset`:

```
CREATE dbo.YourProc @StartDate date, @EndDate DATE --Or datetime2, etc, depending on requirement
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT [PROBLEMCODE],
           DATETIMEINIT,
           [STATUS]
    FROM [Cityworks].[azteca].[REQUEST]
    WHERE REQCATEGORY IN ('WATER', 'SEWER')
    AND [DATETIMEINIT] >= @STARTDATE
      AND DATETIMEINIT < @ENDDATE;

END;
```